# Git and binary data

Tags: git

I'm currently starting to use git for my version control system, however I do a fair bit of web/game development which of course requires images(binary data) to be stored. So if my understanding is correct if I commit an image and it changes 100 times, if I fetch a fresh copy of that repo I'd basically be checking out all 100 revisions of that binary file?

Is this not an issue with large repo's where images change regularly wouldn't the initial fetch of the repo end up becoming quite large? Has anybody experienced any issue's with this in the real world? I've seen a few alternatives for instance, using submodules and keeping images in a separate repo but this only keeps the codebase smaller, the image repo would still be huge. Basically I'm just wondering if there's a nice solution to this.

Comment: This is a design limitation of git. It was written to do one thing well: manage the Linux source tree, which is pretty much all plain text. Git is all about diffs and merges, things which don't really apply to images. If your media files are really large or frequently edited, you're better off using a different mechanism to store the history of those files, and if you're not really collaborating on the code or making lots of branches, then you may be better off not using git at all.

Comment: git will cope with binary files, and the system it uses for *storing* deltas is based on binary content (the text diffs you see in patches are calculated on the fly, not a representation of what's stored). Having said that, xdelta for compressed images isn't likely to reduce the space requirement much. You could save all your images as XPM or BMP :p

Comment: If you want 100 versions of an image, then you will necessarily need to store 100 images somewhere, regardless of the VCS you use. If you have a git server, you can dump the images on the server and just shallow clone to a small depth. if you need to go back to `version0` then of course, you will need to download the entire repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't call that "checkout", but yes, the first time you fetch repository, provided that binary data is huge and incompressible it's going to be what it is - huge. And yes, since conservation law is still in effect breaking it into modules won't save you space and time on initial pulling of repository.

One possible solution is still using separate repository and `--depth` option when pulling it. Shallow repositories have some limitations, but I don't remember what exactly, since I never used it. Check the docs. Keyword is "shallow".

**Edit**: From `git-clone(1)`:

> A shallow repository has a number of
>   limitations (you cannot clone or fetch
>   from it, nor push from nor into it),
>   but is adequate if you are only
>   interested in the recent history of a
>   large project with a long history, and
>   would want to send in fixes as
>   patches.

Comment: Interesting if you take into mind the above doc quote it almost seems that a non distributed vcs might be better for binary data, as you are missing alot of the advanatages of using git when dealing with binary data anyway.

Comment: Yes, but you may still take the pain of fetching huge repository once. Also, you can use separate non-git repository for binary data. But since I really love git (though was sceptical at first about it - everything Linus writes will be praised), I'd suggest separating binary data and... well, dealing with it separately ;-)

Answer (score 3):

What I do is make the images ignored/untracked directories, and then sync the image directory/directories using other, non-git systems (or just manually copy the image directory changes once, when you're talking about alot of images that you don't need to keep completely synced).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately git is not really made for storing binary data. Because it is distributed you would be pulling all versions of all files whenever you clone it. It also becomes ridiculously difficult to prune those large binary files out of your code repository. More about that here: (http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/2009/09/08/the-definitive-step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-delete-a-directory-permanently-from-git-on-widnows-for-dumbasses-like-myself/).

I would recommend trialing it but keep binary files separately from the code (i.e. using submodules). In that case if it doesn't work out for you, you can use another solution without rewriting the whole history for your main repository.

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion of large file storage with GIT here:  http://blog.deveo.com/storing-large-binary-files-in-git-repositories/

I came across this SO question as part of my research and I thought that I would point folks to the blog entry I've already reviewed ( spoiler alert, they recommend [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) for non-windows users ). .